# Can't grab date from input field and turn into date object in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, internet-explorer-8

Having yet again, IE related problems.
The idea is:
in each td, checkboxes have dates assigned to them in the data-name attribute.
When the form is submitted i'm trying to check to see if the dates they checked are consecutive and if they're consecutive, update the hidden fields with the start and end date for more calculations on the next page e.g prices, specials etc. This works fine in real browsers like Chrome and firefox. But IE (and safari I suspect) have issues. Doing some alerts I see that the dates are NaN. Here is a snippet:

The HTML:

```
<td><input data-name="30/10/2013" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input data-name="31/10/2013" type="checkbox"></td>
<td><input data-name="1/11/2013" type="checkbox"></td>

<form id="booking0" onsubmit="return bookingValidation(0)" class="bookings" method="post" action="/anotherpage.asp">
<input type="hidden" name="bookStart" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="bookEnd" value="">
<input class="book" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
function bookingValidation(formIdentifier){
    var start = 0;
    var checkTheDate;
    var currentDate;
    var diff;
    var days;
    var validity = false;
    var checkCounter = 0

$("tr#row"+formIdentifier).find('td').each(function (){
    var date = $(this).find('input');
    if(!date.attr('data-name') == null || !date.attr('data-name') == "") { //if it exists, check to see if it is checked.
        if( date.prop('checked') ){ //If checkbox is checked

            checkCounter++; // if current checkbox is checked, increment.
            if(start == 0){ //if start == 0, then this is the first date. We want to pass the date value into the forms hidden field    

                checkTheDate = new Date(date.attr('data-name')); //this is first check box that is checked. grab the associated date and save it

                                    $('#booking'+formIdentifier).find('input[name=bookStart]').val(jsToVbDate(checkTheDate)); //set both start and end date, incase customer wants to do a 1 day trip
                $('#booking'+formIdentifier).find('input[name=bookEnd]').val(jsToVbDate(checkTheDate));

                start++; //increment so this if statement will never become true
                validity = false; 
            }
            else{ //

                checkTheDate.setDate( checkTheDate.getDate() + 1); //increment check date to hopefully match current date

                currentDate = new Date(date.attr('data-name')); //grab current date 


                diff = new Date(currentDate - checkTheDate); //subtract current date from check date, will return in milliseconds
                days = diff/1000/60/60/24; //convert milliseconds into days
                if(days <= 0){ //if days is less than or equal to 0, this means that the check date and current date are the same, meaning the checkboxes are consecutive
                    $('#booking'+formIdentifier).find('input[name=bookEnd]').val(jsToVbDate(currentDate)); //update end date with current date

                    validity = true;//passes validation, can continue onto booking
                }
                else{
                    alert("Checks must be consecutive");
                    validity = false; //fails validation, can not continue to booking
                    return false; 
                }
            } 
        } //2nd if
    } //1st if
}); //end .each() loop

//checks how many checkboxes were checked. If 1 or less were checked, validation failed.
if (checkCounter <= 1){
    alert("You must select at a minimum of 2 days");
    validity = false;
}
return validity;
```

}

```
function jsToVbDate(dateToFormat){
    var bookStartY = dateToFormat.getFullYear();
    var bookStartM = dateToFormat.getMonth()+1;
    var bookStartD = dateToFormat.getDate();
    var dateToFormat = bookStartY + "-" + bookStartM + "-" + bookStartD;
    return dateToFormat;
}
```

Please help! I'm starting to tear my hair out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like IE is not able to use the date format used, you can use [$.datepicker.parseDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate) to parse a date with custom format

```
checkTheDate = $.datepicker.parseDate( 'd/mm/yy', date.data('name'));
```

Comment: `date.data('name')` is better.

Comment: @TusharGupta yes... was not looking at that... changed

Comment: I tried using date.date('name') but I still get NaN in my alerts through IE. still works fine in chrome, firefox and opera

Comment: @AkiraDawson it is `date.data('name')`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes I did that, I just spelled it wrong on here lol!

Comment: I DID IT!!
I had to get the value
checkTheDate = date.data('name');
parse it
checkTheDate = $.datepicker.parseDate( 'dd/mm/yy', checkTheDate);

Either way I made a break through thanks to you guys, thanks heaps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the checkboxes aren't in the form.

Anyway, to convert "1/11/2013" to a date (assuming d/m/y), use a function like:

```
function toDate(s) {
  var bits = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(bits[2], --bits[1], bits[0]);
}
```

Note parsing of date strings is largely implementation dependent, and often "m/d/y" order is expected. Manual parsing is by far the best method.